# SAS function for using 'power' / exponential

Tags: sas, exponent

I may be missing something obvious, but how do you calculate 'powers' in SAS?

Eg  X squared, or Y cubed?

what I need is to have variable1 ^ variable2, but cannot find the syntax...  (I am using SAS 9.1.3)

Comment: SAS syntax doesn't always follow the established conventions (probably because the syntax is so old). The <>-operator is particulary nasty, as it's interpreted as max and because SAS interprets 0 and missing as false and anything else as true.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

got it!  there is no function.

you need to do:

variable1 ** variable2;

Answer (score 6):

```
data t;
  num = 5;
  pow = 2;
  res = num**pow;
run;
proc print data = t;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the POWER function and, if necessary, the CONSTANT function.

```
nbr_squared = power(nbr, 2);
nbr_cubed = power(nbr, 3);
E_to_the_power_2 = power(constant('E'),2);
```

Comment: Not sure why this got two upvotes, but it's incorrect; there is no POWER function in base SAS, unless you implement it yourself.  The ** operator is the correct answer.

Comment: @Joe, `power()` is valid in `proc ds2` now.

Comment: @whymath Perhaps, but this is certainly not a PROC DS2 question.